# Get current customer id in "Customer Information section" backend?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

How to get current customer id in "Customer Information section" backend ?

Comment: Where do you want to get the customer id? Is that in the block or in a template?

Comment: In after save customer observer admin

Comment: Can you be more specific about where that file is?